# Prove that an Abel group whose order doesn’t include square factor is a cyclic group.

Tags: group-theory

> “Prove that an Abel group whose order doesn’t include square factor is a cyclic group.”

How to prove this?

If $G$ is a group which fulfills this condition, can we say 
$|G|=p_1p_2...p_n$ (each $p_i$ is different prime number) ?

Comment: What do you know about finite abelian groups?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element $g_p \in G$ of order $p$ for each prime $p$ dividing the order of $G$. What is the order of the product of the $g_p$?

Comment: The order of the product of the gp is p? So we can say every subgroup of G is circlic group and therefore G is circlic group?